# Error n tweets were requested but the API can only return 0

Tags: r, api, twitter

I am unable to retrieve any tweets using twitteR package in R. For example this request:

```
nbahash_tweets = searchTwitter("#nba",since='2013-01-01', until='2014-02-25',n=20)
```

Shows me this warning message:

> Warning message: In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params,
>   retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :   20 tweets were requested but
>   the API can only return 0

What could be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

From the official Twitter Search API documentation

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.

so you can't search the API for tweets from 2013 - 2014

Answer (score 2):

I also received this message when I was attempting to use the twitteR package to search Twitter-which brought me to this post.
However, when I used the search_twitter_and_store command in the same package I was able to retrieve 1702 messages and store them in MySQL.  Not exactly what I was shooting for but it did allow me to get and manipulate the data.  Might work for you too.