# Loop in Twitter SearchTwitter() in R

Tags: r, loops, twitter

I am trying to create loop in the twitter `searchTwitter()` function with regard to multiple locations. My code follows below. I am receiving the response:

> Warning message:In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  : 10 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0.

Is it even possible to loop the geocode in this function?
Many thanks in advance!

```r
library(twitteR)

#E.g. for two locations (best case scenario is to upload a file with several locations)

GEOCODE <- "40.7128,-74.0060,20mi;38.2980,-76.5280,20mi"
GEOCODE <- unlist(strsplit(GEOCODE,";"))

tweets = list()

for(i in 1:length(GEOCODE)){
  result <- searchTwitter(searchString = KEYWORD, n=10, geocode = GEOCODE[i])
  tweets <- c(tweets, result)
  tweets <- unique(tweets)
}
```

Comment: See this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39992266/1422451). It seems the API only allows searches in last 7 days. Maybe there are no tweets at those geocodes in last week?

Comment: Thanks! I have checked these codes without the loop and these work though.. I was wondering whether the problem was because of my code or because twitter api does not allow for this

Comment: Add a `Sys.sleep(#)` at end of loop with `#` being number of seconds since some APIs need time between requests.